# PHP image display from mysql from different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a used car website for a class. I have a mysql database that has two tables. One for the car details and one table for car photos. I am trying to display 1 single photo of the car next to some details (like you see on cars.com) but I am struggling. The car id is one one table and the "ext_1" in on another table.

```
<?php

$page_title = "List cars";

require_once ('includes/header.php');
require_once('includes/database.php');

//select statement
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory_tbl, inventory_photos_tbl";
//execute the query
$query = $conn->query($sql);

//Handle selection errors
if (!$query) {
$errno = $conn->errno;
$errmsg = $conn->error;
echo "Selection failed with: ($errno) $errmsg<br/>\n";
$conn->close();
//require_once ('includes/footer.php');
exit;
}
//display results in a table
?>
<h2>Inventory</h2>

<table border="1px solid" border="collapse" align ="center" height='300'  width='750' >
<tr><center>
            <th></th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Make</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Mileage</th>
            <th>Price</td>
    <th>Details</th>
</center>
</tr>

<?php
//insert a row into the table for each row of data
    while (($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) !==NULL){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><img src =" .$row['id']. $row['ext_1']. " width = 100     height = 100></td>";
        echo "<td>", $row['year'], "</td>";
        echo "<td>", $row['make'], "</td>";
        echo "<td>", $row['model'], "</td>";
        echo "<td>", number_format($row['mileage']), "</td>";
        echo "<td>","$", number_format($row['price']), "</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='cardetails.php?id=", $row['id'],"'>View Details</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

```
<?php
// clean up resultsets when we're done with them!
$query->close();

// close the connection.
$conn->close();

//include the footer
require_once ('includes/footer.php');
```

Comment: Without knowing the query (what you wrote in your code), how any one can help ?

Comment: Give table structure of both the table + the code what you tried

Comment: Please, provide more information about the query you are using and de problemas you had so far.

Comment: Do the tables relate in some way?

Comment: The query which you have written just now is wrong. Please provide table structure (table and column name)

Comment: your query is missing a join statement.  you need to join on the car id.  `WHERE inventory_tbl.id = inventory_photos_tbl.ext_1`

Comment: edited with everything I have from the page

Comment: you are still missing the join condition ;)

Comment: the tables are related by an id number.

Comment: I tried the join statement you provided and still nothing shows. All the data from the inventory table shows. It's just the image that's blank

Comment: I think you need to learn how to query more than one table in a single query. [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: you'll definitely need to join the two tables on the car id.  if you image is stored in the database, i suspect your HTML img tag is not correct. the src attribute should only be the photo.  something like $row['myPhotoColumn'] and not .$row['id']. $row['ext_1']

Comment: I got it to work. @devlincarnate I changed the where to say "WHERE inventory_tbl.id = inventory_photos_tbl.id" and I took out the "$row['id'] in the table. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm moving my answer out of the comments, so future readers are able to benefit from the solution.

First, the query needs to qualify the join condition, so change the query to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory_tbl, inventory_photos_tbl WHERE inventory_tbl.id = inventory_photos_tbl.ext_1"
```

Second, the img tag should only refer to the photo source/column, so it should be something like:

```
echo "<td><img src =" .$row['myPhotoColumn']. " width = 100     height = 100></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're wanting to do is a left join.  (Join data from the right table into the left table if the data in the right table exists).

Your SQL statement would look like this.

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory_tbl
LEFT JOIN inventory_photos_tbl as images
ON images.ext_1 = car_id";`

Images serves as an alias to your photos table.
You match up images.ext_1 column to the main table's car_id column which is what the ON statement signifies.  Think of it as a where clause for the JOIN

Now you can reference any of the data in the inventory_photos_table you want in your PHP using your $row variable such as $row['image_column_name'].

You'll probably want to wrap the image data in an if statement to show a placeholder image in case there isn't an image associated with the vehicle yet.

Answer (score 0):

As i don't know your table structure. I assumed the relational column name as `'id'` in `inventory_photos_tbl` table.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory_tbl";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
while (($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) !==NULL){
        $carID=$row['id'];

        // In this query, i'm assuming the relational column as 'id'. (If you are having different column name, please change it here itself)
        $imgQuery = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM inventory_photos_tbl WHERE id=$carID LIMIT 0,1");
        while(($rowImg = $imgQuery->fetch_assoc()))
        {
            $carIMG=$rowImg['ext_1'];
        }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><img src ="$carID.$carIMG" width = 100 height = 100></td>";
    echo "<td>", $row['year'], "</td>";
    echo "<td>", $row['make'], "</td>";
    echo "<td>", $row['model'], "</td>";
    echo "<td>", number_format($row['mileage']), "</td>";
    echo "<td>","$", number_format($row['price']), "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='cardetails.php?id=", $row['id'],"'>View Details</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}?>
```

Comment: This works, but results in an extra hit on the db.

Comment: Yeah @Jose'Vargas. I know. But, OP was not able to tell real table structure. So, without `JOIN` i coded it.